# How to check if a Mainwindow button is clicked from main.cpp?

Tags: qt, qt4

Is there any way to check if the Mainwindow button is clicked from main.cpp? I want to excecute the following line when I pressed the Play button of Mainwindow:

```
pipe = popen("mplayer -slave '/home/cinesoft/Desktop/yamuna/songs/first.3gp' &", "w");
```

I also want the following line to execute when the pause button is pressed:

```
fputs("pause\n", pipe);
```

Answer (score 1):

bjoernz is right. You need to use the Signals and Slots mechanisms built into QT.

Why can't you execute that code in the Mainwindow.cpp class instead of main.cpp? Would make life a lot easier.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look under Signals & Slots on this page:
[Programming with Qt](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qt-basic-concepts.html)

[Cross-Platform Applications using Qt](http://www.macresearch.org/cross-platform-applications-using-qt) is also a good reference for Qt programming.